# Detect the last inline method call of a class

Tags: python

Let's say we have a python class with methods **intended to be called one or more times inline**. My goal is to make methods behave differently when they are invoked *last* in an inline chain of calls.

Example:

```
class InlineClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.called = False
             
    def execute(self):
        if self.called:
            print('do something with awareness of prior call')
            return self
            
        else:
            print('first call detected')
            self.called = True
            return self
          
    def end(self):
        print ('last call detected, do something with awareness this is the last call')
        self.called = False
        return self
             
x = InlineClass()      
x.execute().execute().execute().end() # runs 3 execute calls inline and end.
```

The example above only knows it has reached the last inline call once the `end` method is invoked. What I would like to do, in essence, is to make that step redundant

**QUESTION**

Keeping in mind the intent for this class's methods to **always be called one or more times inline**, is there an elegant way to format the class so it is aware it has reached its last inline method call, and not necessitate the `end` call as in the example above.

Comment: Do you do anything different with the result of the final call like iterate over it or print it?

Comment: Couldn't you pass the times you want the function to run as a parameter to the function, and make it use a for loop to run the code multiple times?

Comment: Detecting the end of chaining is not possible. The function has no idea how the return value will be used. As food for thought, what do you think this should do? `a = x.execute(); b = a.execute()`? Python says it has to be the same as `b = x.execute().execute()`; if what you propose were possible, this reasonable expectation would be violated. One trick that is sometimes used is to detect the non-chaining use of the return value (e.g. in Django ORM retrieval): you can chain on the search object to add more conditions to SQL, but using the search object as an iterator triggers the request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of chaining the functions, you can try creating a function that handles passing different parameters depending on how many times the function has been / will be called.
Here is some example code:

```
class Something:
    def repeat(self, function, count):
        for i in range(count):
            if i == 0:
                function("This is the first time")
            elif i == count - 1:
                function("This is the last time")
            else:
                function("This is somewhere in between")
    def foo_function(self, text):
        print(text)

foo = Something()
foo.repeat(foo.foo_function, 5)
foo.repeat(foo.foo_function, 2)
foo.repeat(foo.foo_function, 6)
foo.repeat(foo.foo_function, 8)
```

Output:

```
This is the first time
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is the last time
This is the first time
This is the last time
This is the first time
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is the last time
This is the first time
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is somewhere in between
This is the last time
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return modified copies instead of `self`, here is the example with behaviour you described:

```py
class InlineClass:
    def __init__(self, counter=0):
        self.counter = counter

    def execute(self):
        return InlineClass(self.counter+1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'InlineClass<counter={self.counter}>'


x = InlineClass()
print(x)
# => InlineClass<counter=0>

y = x.execute().execute().execute()
print(y)
# => InlineClass<counter=3>

print(x.execute().execute().execute())
# => InlineClass<counter=3>

print(y.execute().execute().execute())
# => InlineClass<counter=6>
```

Comment: this would be a good answer for the function to be aware of its first method call vs subsequent, but wouldn't make it aware of the last inline method call. Still good answer tho. Maybe i can rework my approach with that in mind if it is true there is no way to detect the end of chaining.

Comment: I was thinking about your example provided after words "What I would like to do, in essence, is to make that step redundant such as". Looks like it works as you described

Comment: @Fnord If you know how many times each function will be called you could edit the `execute` function to take a parameter n and check if `n==self.counter`. Where n would be the number of the last expected call.